# Write categorical RasterStack to disk with levels/attributes

Tags: r, raster, categorical-data

I have a rasterStack (or RasterBrick) with categorical layers. When I write it to disk, and then load it again, I lose the attributes (e.g. the levels associated to my layers).

I would like to be able to save the attributes of the layers in my .grd file. Is it possible ?

MWE:

```
library(raster)
list_r=list()
for(i in 1:3){
  r=raster(ncol=10, nrow=10, xmx=-80, xmn=-150, ymn=20, ymx=60)
  values(r) <- sample(1:5,size = ncell(r),replace = T)
  
  r <- ratify(r)
  
  rat <- levels(r)[[1]]
  rat$name <- c('A', 'B', 'C','D','E')
  levels(r) <- rat
  list_r[[i]]=r
}
final_r=stack(list_r)
#The levels are included in the rasterStack
levels(final_r)

writeRaster(final_r,filename = "save.grd")

loaded_final_r=stack("save.grd")
#No levels remaining after loading
levels(loaded_final_r)
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not working, but you can save them for a single layer like this

```
x <- writeRaster(final_r[[1]],filename = "save.grd", overwrite=T)
x

#class      : RasterLayer 
#dimensions : 10, 10, 100  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
#resolution : 7, 4  (x, y)
#extent     : -150, -80, 20, 60  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
#source     : save.grd 
#names      : layer.1 
#values     : 1, 5  (min, max)
#attributes :
# ID name
#  1    A
#  2    B
#  3    C
#  4    D
#  5    E
```